# Qt performance - avoid crashing

Tags: performance, qt, crash

I have such problem with my application that´s running in real time.
It´s getting values an plotting two graphs. Also is updating a few (8) QLabels and displaying them in window. The application should run for a very long time and processing data so I wanted to test it in faster regime and I set the sending values to the application for  each 10ms. When I start the application everything works fine, but after some time QLabels stuck or plotting graphs stuck and in the end application crashes.

I would like to ask if 10ms is too fast for updating QLabels and graphs (QCustomPlot) and that is the reason of crashing the program or I need to search for the problem somewhere else?

```
void mainWnd::useDataFromPipe(double val) {

if(val<=*DOF) {
    FSOcounter=FSOcounter+1.0;

    lastRecievedFSO->saveValue(val);
    updateGraphMutex->lock();
    FSOvectorXshort->replace(1, FSOcounter);
    updateGraphMutex->unlock();

    if(!firstDataFSO()) {
        if(val>maximumRecievedFSO->loadValue()) maximumRecievedFSO->saveValue(val);
        else if(val<minimumRecievedFSO->loadValue()) minimumRecievedFSO->saveValue(val);
    }
    else {
       maximumRecievedFSO->saveValue(val);
       minimumRecievedFSO->saveValue(val);
    }
    numberOfRecievedValuesFSO->saveValue(numberOfRecievedValuesFSO->loadValue()+1.0);
}
else {
    RFcounter=RFcounter+1.0;

    lastRecievedRF->saveValue(val);
    updateGraphMutex->lock();
    RFvectorXshort->replace(1, RFcounter);
    updateGraphMutex->unlock();

    if(!firstDataRF()) {
        if(val>maximumRecievedRF->loadValue()) maximumRecievedRF->saveValue(val);
        else if(val<minimumRecievedRF->loadValue()) minimumRecievedRF->saveValue(val);
    }
    else {
       maximumRecievedRF->saveValue(val);
       minimumRecievedRF->saveValue(val);
    }
    numberOfRecievedValuesRF->saveValue(numberOfRecievedValuesRF->loadValue()+1.0);
}
}
```

where saveValue() and loadValue() are

```
void infoLine::saveValue(double val) {
*value=val;
valueLabel->setText(QString("<b>%1</b>").arg(val));
}
double infoLine::loadValue(void) {
return *value;
}
```

Comment: What thread does this code run in?

Comment: It´s running in thread that starts at the end of constructor of mainWnd. The thread has only one function inside: bool mainWnd::readThreadFun() and that function controls if the server (on the other side of pipe) is still running, reads the data and pass them into the function above. The second thread only replot the graph and it´s implemented through QTimer that calls a slot for replotting. This thread is using FSOvectorXshort and RFvectorXshort so I used mutex on it in both threads. But now I´m not sure if it matters that useDataFromPipe() is not slot but a public function.

Comment: I assume that the widgets are only accessed directly from the UI thread? Because everything else will fail as they're not thread-safe. Also, where does it usually crash when you run it in a debugger?

Comment: yes. The widgets are placed in main window "mainWnd" so I passed a pointer of mainWnd to the thread to use the functions of mainWnd. 
The errors seem to appear randomly. Sometimes it crashes after 24000 values recieved, sometimes after 80000. May this be the source of the problem as I´m not using slots to communicate with mainWnd? Respectively is it possible/safe to use invokeMethod() to use methods in mainWnd?

Answer (score 1):

You're not "updating" the labels every 10ms, you're merely calling `setText` or similar methods on them every 10ms. The labels will be updated as dictated by how many events are in the event queue. As long as you "update" the labels by calling `setText` etc., you're OK - this should not be a problem.

A crash is usually due to a memory bug. A memory bug typically can be due to running out of memory, a double free, or access to deallocated memory.

What you describe seems like a memory bug due to running out of memory. The most trivial explanation is that you're leaking memory. That's an easy one - smart pointers (`QScopedPointer` and `QSharedPointer`) will help with that.

You may also not be leaking memory, but recursing too deeply if you indeed recurse into the event loop.

You may also be updating the widget(s) incorrectly, resulting in forced, repeated, expensive repaints that are not compressed into one repaint.

You'd need to show how you "update" the plot. While the labels are implemented correctly, and repeated calls to various QLabel `setXxxx` methods are cheap, the custom plot class may simply be implemented incorrectly.

The idiomatic, and indeed the only correct way of updating a widget in Qt is:

1. Set some data members.
2. Call `update()`.

This is what `QLabel::setText` does internally, and it is what any other widget should be doing as well. This functionality should be exposed in a `setXxxx`-like method, and is an implementation detail, although an important one. The users of the widget don't need to be aware of it.

The update events are posted to the widget and are compressed, such that repeated updates without returning to the event loop result in only one repaint.

It's really hard to tell without seeing a self-contained, *minimal* example. By minimal I mean *nothing* that has no bearing on the issue should be left in.

Comment: OK. I´ve edited the question with the example of code that is processing data. The data I´m getting via pipe connection between two applications. Above this function there are only functions for getting data from pipe, atof() for converting to number and control whether server is not closed. I´m using also function for replotting the qcustomplot but it runs in another thread and its bounded by mutex to not manipulate with QVector while replacing value.